# Use Change Data Capture in the other direction (Heroku -> SF)

Tags: isv, platform-event, heroku, change-data-capture, heroku-connect

I have a **Salesforce ISV app** that shares some data with its **Heroku-based backend**.

To notify the backend about data changes in Salesforce we use `Change Data Capture`. For synching back changes from Heroku to Salesforce we use `Custom Platform Events`.

So far so good. The problem is the CDC-path is effortless and very flexible. If we change the data model the channel magically adapts. But for the way back we need to change the fields of the custom event and adjust code to synchronize it.

**My question is, is there a better way to solve this? Like Change Data Capture in both directions.**

Comment: Robert - just to clarify your use case does not relate to external change data capture documented here if it does then probably this is way to proceed https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer19/release-notes/rn_forcecom_external_data_change_capture_ga.htm

Comment: @Mitesh I heard that External Objects and OData are really expensive and therefore we decided to not go that route.

Comment: RE: "expensive" In the end, you are going to spend the money, either by developing the solution yourself, or by purchasing it - just depends if you value the time to market, not having to worry about the stack, etc.  All of us who are programmers could build the products we buy... but why spend our effort there, if our competitors are just buying the solution and moving to the next problem - also, ask for a "nice guy discount" - see what you can get...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several alternatives...

## REST API

Just update the data. You clearly already have a session ID if you can post events, so why not just call the REST API and cut out the middleman?

## JSON

Create a large field on your event, send a JSON payload through the Platform Event. Deserialize in your Platform Event Trigger, and do whatever post-processing you need to.

Comment: Can't the external Heroku app send CDC events into Salesforce? So that my CDC Apex triggers could just ask where the changes come from and then applies it or not?

Comment: @RobertSösemann CDC is basically a standard Platform Event generated by the platform. As far as I can tell, only Salesforce can generate these events, hence the need for a custom Platform Event if you want ESB-like functionality.